# Spark: Merge RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 1.4 I have two dataframes of different schemas. Let's say:

DF1: stringA, stringB
DF2: stringC

I'd like to merge/combine the two into a single dataframe like:

DF3: stringA, stringB, stringC

I can't seem to find a way to combine the two when they have no key for me to use.

Comment: A dataframe is keyed...are you referring to an RDD?

Comment: Sorry Justin, yeah an RDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `union`

```
rdd.union(rdd2)
```